# SplitViewController DetailView not extending behind TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm using a `UITabBarController` to display a `SplitViewController` inside. Both the MasterView and DetailView have a separate `NavigationController` and a `TableView` inside.

**So far so good, everything is working except, that the DetailViewController isn't extending the edges behind the `TabBar`.**

If I inspect the views you can clearly see the problem:
[image: 3D view of views]

But both the `NavigationController` and `TableViewController` share the same settings in Master and Detail:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for that rather dump mistake, but I found out that I've added `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []` to my `viewDidLoad()` in my DetailViewController.
Removing this fixed my described problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `DetailViewController`'s `NavigationController` doesn't know that there's a `UITabBar`. Try selecting the `NavigationController` and setting "Bottom Bar" in "Simulated Metrics" to "Translucent Tab Bar".

Comment: …and when you do that with the `SplitViewController`?

Comment: No also no changes…

Comment: I'll take a look at it when I'm home 